# Making Safari’s View Controller always go back in history when swiping back

Tags: ios, safari

I spend more time in [Safari View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/504/) (SVC, the in-app browser of apps) than Safari itself, mostly through [Reeder](http://www.reederapp.com/ios/).

Often I navigate away from the original page, starting to build a history. To go back in said history, I need to click the `<` in the bottom left. However, muscle memory often compels me to swipe back instead, which takes me out of SVC and to the app again, making me lose all my navigated history.

Yet sometimes it does take me back in history. I figure it must be something in the way I swipe, but so far I haven’t been able to figure out how to reliably swipe to go back in history.

Ideally for me, swipe back would *always* go back in history, returning to the app only when you were at the firs page; or via pressing `Done`.

Is there really a difference in swipes? Or better yet, a setting to change to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether performing a horizontal left to right edge swipe would navigate to the previous webpage in the in-app browser's navigation history or the previous view controller in the app is something which [could be customized](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414995-allowsbackforwardnavigationgestu?language=objc) by the developer of the app.

So it's likely that you will find one or the other mode implemented among different apps. There's no set standard. Although it's possible for the app developer to provide an in-app setting to switch between the two.

You are right that this has the potential of muscle memory failing on the user by increasing the likelihood of performing the unintended gesture in an app.

Turns out, the way Reeder app is implemented, performing an edge swipe always navigates back to the previous view controller (i.e. out of the browser). As per the current implementation, the behaviour isn't configurable. If you wish to navigate back in browsing history, be careful with the gesture.

You may try [contacting](http://www.reederapp.com/ios/#contact) the developer and share your feedback regarding the same.

Comment: “the way Reeder app is implemented, performing an edge swipe always navigates back to the previous view controller”. That’s my point: it doesn’t. I frequently have one or the other happen in Reeder during the same session.

Comment: @user137369 In that case, contacting the developer of the app should be the resort. It may possibly be due to a bug in the app. The developer should be able to give a concrete answer.

Comment: @NimeshNema I’ve tried contacting Reeder’s dev in the past for other things and never got a reply, but I’ll try again. Do you have any documentation that confirms what the swipe does is up to the developer?

Comment: @user137369 See this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414995-allowsbackforwardnavigationgestu?language=objc

Comment: @NimeshNema Thank you. I think it’s worth it to add that link to your answer.